# apt-get doesn't install latest PHP 5.4 from oldstable sources

Tags: apt, php

I have two servers running 13.04, and at some point I added the [oldstable package sources](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5-oldstable) for PHP 5.4. For some reason I'm not able to update it anymore though — one server doesn't upgrade from 5.4.23 to 5.4.24, and the other one, after a few troubleshooting uninstalls is stuck with 5.4.9 from the default package sources.

Here's the correct version installed on one server:

```
PHP 5.4.23-1+sury.org~raring+1 (cli) (built: Dec 12 2013 09:25:05)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

Here's what I did on the other server:

```
# add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
# apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

But, I get the old version:

```
# php -v
PHP 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.4 (cli) (built: Dec 12 2013 04:29:20)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

I already did an `apt-get remove php* --purge`, followed by an `apt-get install php5`, but no dice: it brought me down from 5.4.23 to 5.4.9.

---

Here's the correct selections I need installed:

```
# dpkg --get-selections | grep php
libapache2-mod-php5         install
php-apc                     install
php-pear                    install
php5                        install
php5-cli                    install
php5-common                 install
php5-curl                   install
php5-gd                     install
php5-imagick                install
php5-mysql                  install
```

The cache doesn't even show the PPA:

```
# apt-cache policy php5
php5:
  Installed: 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.4
  Candidate: 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.4
  Version table:
 *** 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.4 0
        500 http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.4.9-4ubuntu2 0
        500 http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: but php5 version 5.5.3 is available on the repositories.

Comment: I don't care about 5.5.3 — I need the latest 5.4 from the oldstable repositories so that the two servers run the same PHP version.

Comment: If you run `apt-cache search php5` does a option show to install "5.4.24-1+sury.org" ?

Comment: @DashplusJava No, it just lists all kinds of packages without specific version names.

Comment: Try this command please: `sudo apt-get install php5=5.4.24-1+sury.org`

Comment: @DashplusJava Returns `Version '5.4.24-1+sury.org' for 'php5' was not found`

Comment: Ok, well I think I see why now. The PPA you added doesn't have a php5 package for raring ringtail (13.04). The command you just tried should have installed it, if it was available. Maybe it has something to do with 13.04 being out of support now.

Comment: The PPA does have the package for 10.04, 12.04, and 12.10.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 is already EOL, and therefore off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you are unable to install the package you want is because it is no longer in the PPA that you added. The php5 5.4.23-1+sury.org for raring was removed from the PPA.

Here's what the PPA looked like on Dec 16, 2013 : http://web.archive.org/web/20131216111917/https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5-oldstable

You can see that at that time there was a raring package for php5 in the PPA. This is what your other servers have installed. If you look at it today, that package is not there. Ubuntu will not remove a package that has been installed; so your other servers will still have it.

The reason for removing that package from the PPA is probably because Ubuntu 13.04 has ran out of support. It stopped receiving updates in January. Anyone still on 13.04 should upgrade to 13.10.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I could copy the old `.deb`s from `/var/cache/apt` though and install them with `dpkg` – seems to have worked.

Comment: Exactly, I don't support outdated Ubuntu releases.  You should use LTS release if you want to have it for longer time.  (BTW I will be phasing out quantal as well in a very short time, since it's support ends April 2014.)